# Copying the form with the functionality at the click of a button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a form and when I click on the button I have to copy but it doesn't work. Even if it works I can't copy the functionality of the form.I tried to copy to generic form but it doesn't work

> JQ:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var addToWishList = document.querySelector('#add-to-wishlist');
var wishlistItem = document.querySelector('#wishlist-item');
var wishlist = document.querySelector('#wishlist');
var clearlist = document.querySelector('#clearlist');
var saved = localStorage.getItem('wishlistItems');
var add = document.querySelector('#eventBtn');

addToWishList.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (wishlistItem.value.length < 1) return;
    wishlist.innerHTML += '<li>' + wishlistItem.value + '</li>';
    localStorage.setItem('wishlistItems', wishlist.innerHTML);
}, false);

if (saved) {
    wishlist.innerHTML = saved;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#clearlist").click(function() {
    localStorage.clear();
    $("#list li").empty();
    });

});

add.click(function(){
    addToWishList.clone(true).appendTo("body");
  });
});
```

> And my form:

```
      <form id="add-to-wishlist">
      <button type="button" id="eventBtn">Add new list</button>
      <label><h1>To do list</h1></label>
      <input type="text" name="wishlist-item" id="wishlist-item">
      <button type="submit">Add to Wishlist</button>
      <button type="reset" id="clearlist">Delete records</button>
      <ul id="list">
        <li id="wishlist"></li>
      </ul>
     </form>
``
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 issues with your approach:
1) ids have to be unique, otherwise your HTML isn't valid and won't work as expected. It's better to change to classes instead. Otherwise it would be necessary to e.g. increment a value each time you clone the form and change all ids of the cloned elements accordingly.
2) To set any event on a dynamically created element, it's necessary to delegate this event from an already existing parent element of this element that's already there when the page is initially loaded, e.g. from document.
I adjusted your code accordingly and adjusted the events to work with the specific form. The code isn't working in a stack snippet here because of the local storage, but here's a working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jnLysdxb/).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var saved = localStorage.getItem('wishlistItems');

  $(document).on("click", ".add", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let wishlistItem = $(this).closest("form").find(".wishlist-item");
    let wishlist = $(this).closest("form").find(".wishlist");
    if (wishlistItem.val().length < 1) return;
    wishlist.append('<li>' + wishlistItem.val() + '</li>');
    localStorage.setItem('wishlistItems', wishlist.html());
  });

  if (saved) {
    $(".wishlist:eq(0)").html(saved);
  }

  $(document).on("click", ".clearlist", function() {
    localStorage.clear();
    $(this).closest("form").find(".list li").remove();
  });

  $(document).on("click", ".eventBtn", function() {
    let newList = $(this).closest("form").clone();
    newList.find(".list li").empty();
    newList.find(".wishlist-item").empty();
    newList.appendTo("body")
  });
});
```

```html
 <form class="add-to-wishlist">
   <button type="button" class="eventBtn">Add new list</button>
   <label>
     <h1>To do list</h1>
   </label>
   <input type="text" name="wishlist-item" class="wishlist-item">
   <button class="add">Add to Wishlist</button>
   <button type="reset" class="clearlist">Delete records</button>
   <ul class="list">
     <li class="wishlist"></li>
   </ul>
 </form>
```

Comment: @YuriiSerhiichuk Glad that I was able to help :) If this answered your question, please check the checkmark next to the answer so your question is resolved as answered/solved.